# How to create a select field that loads elements on the fly in rails for a many-to-many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a  field that lets people select an article, that they want to connect with the present article to:

```
<%= form_for(Relation.create, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :dependent_id, :value => @article.id %>
  <%= f.collection_select :dependency_id, Article.all.reject{|x| (x.dependency_hack.map{|x| x.dependent_id}.include?  @article.id) &&
                                                                 (if current_user then x.dependency_hack.map{|x| x.user}.include? current_user end) ||
                                                                  x.id == @article.id}, :id, :title, {} %>
  <%= f.submit "Add suggestion" %>
<% end %>
```

But this loads all article titles, which is wasteful and slow. Instead, titles should be loaded dynamically, after the user types a few characters.

Comment: Make a google search how to do dynamic select tags using jQuery or JavaScript

Comment: re "hard to read": people don't need to understand how that part works to answer the question.

Comment: re "dynamic select tags using jQuery": what people mean by this is apparently that "based on what is selected in one select element, values in another select element are updated accordingly.

Comment: You probably are after an autocomplete field with a remote datasource. There are tons of javascript libraries out there that'll help you with that, suggesting one would turn into an opinion-based game

Comment: I'm sure RailsCasts has an ajax select / search / select2 tutorial.

Comment: I googled a lot but I don't find tutorials explaining how to do this with a many-to-many association.